# Movie where an invading alien spaceship crashes and is frozen in Russia/Siberia/Mongolia

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Within the last couple of years I watched a movie where some people realize that an invading alien spaceship had crashed in some place like Russia or Siberia, where it's icy most of the time.  The only reason the invasion didn't proceed was because the alien ship and alien were frozen.

A group of these people fly in an old cargo plane to the icy location, to search and destroy the alien spaceship and aliens.  I can't remember much else, except maybe two of the protagonists were father and son.  The movie had to have been made no earlier than 2019.  Seems like a lot of people die in the final showdown with the alien, but the two men (father and son?) survive and kill the alien.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This was a live-action movie?  Where did you see it?  Was it in English?

Comment: Any familliar faces in the cast? Do you remember any special effects?

Answer (score 26):

The Tomorrow War (aired on Amazon)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tomorrow_War

> Dan and Emmy later deduce that the White Spikes arrived on Earth earlier than 2048 as there was never a record of their ship arriving. After finding volcanic ash on a White Spike's claw, Dan and Charlie consult with Dan's student, Martin, an amateur volcanologist. They determine that the White Spikes have been on Earth at least since the "Millennium Eruption" in 946 AD.
>
> Dan leads a mission to Russia with Charlie, Dorian, the stranded future soldiers, and his estranged father James, a Vietnam veteran. They find the alien ship frozen in ice beneath the Academy of Sciences Glacier, and surmise that global warming freed them in the future. Additionally, the frozen bodies of a reptilian-like alien species are also found on board, causing the group to deduce that the ship had crash landed on Earth, and that the White Spikes were engineered to help wipe out the native population of a planet in order to allow them to colonize. They then inject the lethal toxin into several White Spikes who have been in a state of hypersleep. This awakens the rest of the colony, who begin to attack. After awakening, the queen White Spike escapes.

Comment: My first thought as well. The scene occurs later in the movie